# Query about derivation for the grand partition function for an ideal fermi gas

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, fermions, partition-function

I am having trouble understanding the following derivation:
[image]

I am having a bit of trouble understanding what it means to sum over all states. 
So this is how I am interpreting the above.

We have a gas of $N$ particles in different states $n_1, n_2, n_3,...$ with energies $Ɛ_1, Ɛ_2, Ɛ_3,...$ etc.

In the above derivation $E$ is just the total energy, given by $$\sum_{i=1}^{i=\infty} {n_iƐ_i}, $$

and $N$ is just the sum of the occupancies $n_1 + n_2 + n_3 + ...$.

My issue might be more with the mathematical notation than the physics but when we have a sum like the one above, the different terms in the sum are given by the indice $i$, i.e $$\sum_{i=1}^{i=\infty} {n_iƐ_i} ,$$ = $n_1Ɛ_1 + n_2Ɛ_2 + n_3Ɛ_3 +...$.

What are the different terms in the sum given by line 2 in the above derivation? 
I can't even write the second term in the above sum as I don't see what the summing indice is.

Secondly, I don't understand what the logic is going from line 3 to line 4 is.

If someone understands the above derivation can you please explain it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The index $i$ in $n_i$ and $\epsilon_i$ refers to the label of the one-particle states. I.e., the Hamiltonian $\hat H_N$ of the non-interacting gas of $N$ particles is written as a sum of $N$ one-particle Hamiltonian $\hat h_{\alpha}$:
$$
\hat H_N= \sum_{\alpha=1}^N \hat h_{\alpha}
$$
and the eigenstates of $\hat h_{\alpha}$ are the states $\left| i\right>$ such that
$$
\hat h_{\alpha}\left| i\right>=\epsilon_i \left| i\right>.
$$
In general, the number of the one-particle states is infinite ($i=1, \dots, \infty$).

$N$-particle states are obtained as symmetrized or anti-symmetrized tensor products of $N$ of such one-particle states. The corresponding $N$-particle energy, $E_N$, is just the sum of the one particle energy for each state, each multiplied by the number of particles which are in that state  (the occupation numbers $n_i$):
$$
E_N= \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} n_i \epsilon_i,
$$
with the constraint $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} n_i=N$. Therefore, one could say that a single $N$_particle state is uniquely identified by the infinite set of occupation numbers $\left\{ n_i \right\}$, or equivalently by the ordered sequence $(n_1,n_2,n_3,\dots)$, always with the constraint $\sum_{i=1} n_i=N$.

Now, let's go to grand-canonical statistical mechanics. Your starting expression is a possible way to slightly simplify the derivation, by starting immediately with a sum ove all the states, without any constraint on the number of particles. It is a way to get almost immediately the correct final result for the gran-canonical partition function.

It could be interesting and probably pedagogically more useful to start with the expression for the gran canonical partition function, written as:
$$
\mathcal{Z} = \sum_{N=0}^{\infty} e^{\beta \mu N} Q_N ~~~~~~~~~~~[1]
$$
where $Q_N$ is the canonical partition function for a system of $N$ particles.
$$
Q_N=\sum_{\left\{ n_i \right\}; \sum_{i=1} n_i=N   } e^{-\beta E_N(\left\{ n_i \right\})}.
$$
The constraint $ \sum_{i=1} n_i=N $ can be absorbed into a Konecker's delta, in order to rewrite $Q_N$ as an unconstrained the sum over all possible values of the occupation numbers:
$$
Q_N=\sum_{\left\{ n_i \right\}  } e^{-\beta E_N(\left\{ n_i \right\})}\delta_{N,\sum_{i=1} n_i}~~~~~~~~~~[2]
$$.
Using this expression [2], the gran canonical partition function [1] can be rewritten as:

$$
\mathcal{Z} = \sum_{N=0}^{\infty} e^{\beta \mu N}\sum_{\left\{ n_i \right\}  } e^{-\beta E_N(\left\{ n_i \right\})}\delta_{N,\sum_{i=1} n_i}=
\sum_{N=0}^{\infty} \sum_{\left\{ n_i \right\}  } e^{\beta \mu N}e^{-\beta E_N(\left\{ n_i \right\})}\delta_{N,\sum_{i=1} n_i}=
\sum_{N=0}^{\infty} \sum_{\left\{ n_i \right\}  } e^{\beta \mu \sum_{i=1}^N n_i}e^{-\beta E_N(\left\{ n_i \right\})}\delta_{N,\sum_{i=1} n_i}=
\sum_{N=0}^{\infty} \sum_{\left\{ n_i \right\}  } e^{-\beta \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} n_i (\epsilon_i-\mu)}\delta_{N,\sum_{i=1} n_i}
$$ 
In the last formula, it is possible to invert the order of summation, leaving an *external*, unconstrained sum over all the possible choices of occupation numbers, while the sum over $N$ of the Kronecker's delta, for each choice of of the occupation numbers $\left\{ n_i \right\} $, is equal to $1$ (only one value of $N$ is equal to $\sum_i n_i $ ).

Therefore, we have arrived to the unconstrained sum over the occupation numbers.
Its explicit meaning is 
$$
\sum_{\left\{ n_i \right\}  }=\sum_{n_1}\sum_{n_2}\sum_{n_3}\dots.
$$
So that, if each term in the sum is factorized [1] gets factorized as 
$$
\left(\sum_{n_1} e^{-\beta n_1 (\epsilon_1-\mu)}\right)\left(\sum_{n_2} e^{-\beta n_2 (\epsilon_2-\mu)}\right)\left(\sum_{n_3} e^{-\beta n_3 (\epsilon_3-\mu)}\right)\dots.
$$
At this point the exact calculation depends on the statistics (two values of each occupation number for fermions, infinite values for bosons), but it is straightforward.

Comment: "What are the different terms in the sum given by line 2 in the above derivation? I can't even write the second term in the above sum as I don't see what the summing indice is." Was my main question, from your answer, is the answer to the question that the sum is over the set of possible occupancy numbers, such that the total gives N? Just to confirm

Comment: @VishalJain the meaning of the sum over occupation numbers is explicitly written in the last but one equation in my answer: on has to sum (in any order) ,over all possible values of $n_1$, something which is a sum over all possible values of $n_2$,  something which is a sum over all possible values of $n_3$ and so on.